# How to print select lines of a text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, text-files, line

I have a text file with multiple lines of text. Each line of text is split into two columns, separated by a comma. How do I write a program to print only the lines of the text file that have a specific value for the first column? So for example how do I write a program to print every line that has "hello" as the first column?

I'm using python 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

# read the file line by line
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # split the line
        columns = line.split(",")

        # print all lines with "hello" as the first column
        if columns[0] == "hello":
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Perhaps the lack of any non-code text, but I think it is fine (as edited), and should be accepted, so I bumped it back up to 0.  Note: line.split(',') always returns a non-empty list.